# Obtaining the current normal in LWGL

Tags: java, opengl, minecraft

I have a simple question.

I'm working on a Minecraft mod that requires me to disable the horrible-looking scaling set through glOrtho() and specify my own so I may draw a nice, non-pixelated string. If you've ever seen Minecraft, the fonts look horrible.

In my mod I'm using Slick (A 2D Java game API) to render strings and load fonts. I've correctly set up Slick and have seen fonts drawn appropriately on menus. The only problem is that in my resetting of the matrices...

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);      // Select Projection
GL11.glPushMatrix();      // Push The Matrix
GL11.glLoadIdentity();        // Reset The Matrix
GL11.glOrtho(0, Minecraft.getMinecraft().displayWidth,                 Minecraft.getMinecraft().displayHeight, 0, 3000.0D, -3000.0D);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select Modelview Matrix
GL11.glPushMatrix();    // Push The Matrix
GL11.glLoadIdentity();    // Reset The Matrix
```

I loose the translation and scale set in previous functions. (Ones I haven't written)

I can obtain the current scale factor quite easily through source already written by Mojang, the creators of this game. If I can get the scale and normal before resetting the matrices, I'm hoping I might have a chance at getting these strings properly rendered on a 1-to-1 pixel scale (offering optimal display resolution).

So, bottom line: How can I get the translation and scale information in LWGL? Or, given my situation, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pushing the matrices. This mandates you to balance this out with the same amount of `glPopMatrix()` calls, so that the stack doesn't overflow. each `glPushMatrix` `glPopMatrix` pair acts like a set of "braces". After a closing `glPopMatrix` the matrix state of the stack as before the call to the corresponding `glPushMatrix` is restored.

However! OpenGL is not a scene graph and the matrix stack doesn't define a "current position" or a "current scaling". It defines a transformation from model space to eye space (modelview matrix) and from eye space to clip space (projection). That, and nothing more is, what matrices do. There's no scene, there's no objects, there's no internal storage about positions and stuff like that in OpenGL. So I think you must adjust your ideas about OpenGL a little bit.